# SharePoint List - getting the data from a CMP file

Tags: sharepoint, wordpress

I had a weblog (discussion list) on a SharePoint server, and I no longer have access to the server.  I would like to get the data out, so that I can republish into a WordPress site.

I already have an export of the list in a .CMP file.  I do not have access to original server or to a replica or backup of the server.

An ideal solution is something that will allow me to import the .CMP file into WordPress, but that looks like a long putt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd try is creating a new temprary sharepoint site from the CMP file, then use access 2007 to get teh data into a database which can then be manipulated into a format that can be imported.  Take a look at this post: [Migrating your SharePoint blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/cgross/archive/2009/09/05/migrating-your-sharepoint-blog.aspx)

Comment: Assuming I can get access to a SharePoint server, this looks like a good start.

Comment: If you don't have access to a server download an eval copy of server 2008 and run it in a vm